# ngRoute not working in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I have the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="~/styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/styles/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="appName">
    <a href="/view1">view1</a>
    <a href="/view1">view2</a>
   <div>
    this is a dynamic message:  {{message}}
</div>
<div ng-view>

</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('appName', ['ngRoute']);

        app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeController'
            })
                .when('/view1', {
                    templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
                    controller: 'FirstController'
                })
                .when('/view2', {
                    templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html',
                    controller: 'SecondController'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
        });
        app.controller('FirstController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = 'first controller';
        });
        app.controller('SecondController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = 'Second controller';
        });
        app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = 'Home controller';
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but when i click on the view1 or view2 anchor tag, nothing is happening and i get an error like this
[resource not found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiSfx.png)

I dont get any error in the console, can anyone help me to figure out what exactly is wrong.

Comment: what do you mean by server, i use cdn

Comment: a # is missing in your links : `href="#/view1"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html you miss 
ngview directive add it.

`<div ng-view></div>`

For further help see this link 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/

Comment: could you please check my code, i actually have a ng-view directive

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-view` to display content and you missed `#` at anchor tag

```
<body ng-app="appName">
    <a href="#/view1">view1</a>
    <a href="#/view1">view2</a>
   <div ng-view>
    this is a dynamic message:  {{message}}
   </div>
   <script>
    <!-- script here -->
   </script>
</body>
```

Comment: have you actually tried it, please use my code and try it because it is not working for me

Comment: So, finally you decided that I marked down the question. Even you don't know who marked down the question but you are blaming me for that

Answer (score -1):

You don't have ng-view

add following in html to get the pages loaded

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

Try this for app config

```
app.config(function (locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
            $locationProvider.hashPrefix('#');
            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeController'
            })
                .when('/view1', {
                    templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
                    controller: 'FirstController'
                })
                .when('/view2', {
                    templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html',
                    controller: 'SecondController'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
        });
```